# Trouble Updating State with React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Route exact path ="/" component={AuthPage} />
          <Route exact path ="/login" component={AuthPage} />
          <Route exact path ="/register" component={AuthPage} />
          <Route exact path ="/homepage" component={Homepage} />
          <Route exact path ="/notloggedin" component={NotLoggedIn} />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my action

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
import { SET_CURRENT_USER } from './types';

export const checkUser = user => (dispatch) => {
    fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          if (json.status === 200) {
              localStorage.setItem("jwt", json.jwt);
              const { jwt } = json
              const { user_name } = jwt_decode(jwt);
              dispatch({
                    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
                    payload: user_name
                })
              window.location = '/homepage' 
          } else {
              alert(json.message)
          }    
      });
  };
```

Here is my reducer

```
import { SET_CURRENT_USER } from '../actions/types'

const initialState = {
    user: ''
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_CURRENT_USER:
            return {
                user: action.payload,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I can set an alert inside of the reduction to show action.payload and it appears [alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrb2n.png)

But Redux Dev Tools show no update to state [redux dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyIWc.png)

Why isn't state being updated?

Comment: I don't see why your state _would_  update because it's not executing that part of the code.  I think `json.status === 200` is never going to be true because your json response will be a _string_ not a number.  Does it work if you either change it to compare against a string or just remove the condition entirely?

Comment: That part is working and dispatch is getting triggered. I'm sending a status code with the data from my API.

Comment: How are you setting up the store? Are you using combineReducers or just passing it the user reducer only. In your image of dev tools it shows currentUser as the parent structure of user.

Comment: I'm using combineReducers but I actually only have one. It's defined in reducers/index.js and the store brings it in as rootReducer

Comment: You probably need to combine the rest of the state when you return in your reducer try `return {...state, user: action.payload}` and see what you get.

Comment: still the same. The action isn't showing up in the dev tools either. But I can also put alert(action.type) inside of the reducer under case: SET_CURRENT_USER: and above the return and it knows. Somehow it's not making it to the store though

Answer (score -1):

The redux dev tools are the problem themself.

They're unpredictable and don't show state effectively.

Better to render to the UI.